# Username and password not accepted by nodemailer coming from a post request

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I'm new to stack overflow so go easy on me, I'm trying to incorrupt an email form into my website, I'm using nodemailer with a Gmail account. I seem to be having trouble with my login, i keep getting the error:
code: 'EAUTH',
response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
'535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b16-20020a05600010d000b0031aef72a021sm1535333wrx.86 - gsmtp',
responseCode: 535,
command: 'AUTH PLAIN'

I've verified my Gmail key is correct, my address is correct, I've tried different ports and secure false/true on different ports, I've tried different email accounts (i currently only have Gmail accounts but I'd prefer to use this Gmail one). I'm at a loss.

I also keep getting linked to this page and I think if I see it again I will scream. I cannot see an option to turn on or off less secure apps. https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

I have enabled 2fa on my Gmail account through a 2fa key. I have an app key. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. here is the code for the mailer, the path and the error.

I have removed my email but it's displayed publicly on my site so I'm not worried about it being in my code, the private key is in a folder, i have verified that it works.

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

// email form
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: "****@gmail.com",
    pass: privateKeys.gmailKey,
  },
});

app.post('/email', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Extract form data
    const {  emailName, emailAddress, emailContent } = req.body;

    console.log(emailName, emailAddress, emailContent)
    
    // Set up email data
    const mailOptions = {
      from: emailAddress,              // sender address from the form
      to: "****@gmail.com",  // your address
      subject: `Message from ${emailName}`, // Subject line
      text: emailContent,      // plain text body
      // html: "<p>Email Content in HTML if needed</p>", // If you want to send HTML content
    };

    // Send the email
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

    // Send a response to the client
    res.status(200).send("Email sent successfully!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Failed to send email.");
  }
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this here so you can learn from my mistakes. I did everything right but I create the App password on the wrong Gmail account.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).